# Getting Angular value but image is visible only after refreshing the page

Tags: html, angularjs, image

I am displaying userlist using ng-repeat, Am editing the data and uploading a picture. After uploading the data the entire page get refresh but img is not visible, but if i inspect am getting the correct url in src, Once again refresh the page then only image is visible...

My view.ejs

```
<figure ng-if="loading_file==false && nodata==false" ng-repeat="user in userdetailslist | orderBy : 'firstname' | filter:searchtext | filter:{role_id:filterbyrole}" ng-class-even="'right'">
     <div >
    <img ng-if="user.profile_img!=null" data-ng-src="https://{{bucketname}}.s3.amazonaws.com/{{user.user_id}}/profilepic/{{user.profile_img}}" alt="Images" />
    <img ng-if="user.profile_img==null" ng-src="/uploads/default.png" alt="Images" />
    </div>
    <h5>{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</h5>
    <h6>{{user.email}}</h6>
    <h6>Created on {{user.created_date | date: "dd-MMM-yyyy"}}</h6>
    <div class="action_bl">
    <% if(valid_role[1]) { %>
    <span class="action edit" id="edit" ng-hide="deleteclicks">
    <a  ng-click= "edit(user)"   href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
    </span>
    <% } %>
    <% if(valid_role[2]) { %>
    <span class="retore_styl" ng-show="deleteclicks">
    <a   ng-click= "restore(user)" style="color:#7b878d; text-decoration:none" class="fa fa-undo" data-title="Restore" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#restorediag" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
     </span>
    <span class="action" >
    <a ng-click= "delete(user)" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
    </span>
    <% } %>
    </div>
    </figure>
```

My app.js

```
$scope.getuserdata=function(status)
        {
              $scope.loading_file = true;
            $scope.status=status;
            $http.get('/getuserswithstatus/'+$scope.status).then(function(response)
            {
                 $scope.userdetailslist = response.data;  

                 $scope.loading_file = false;
                 if($scope.userdetailslist.length==0)
                 {
                     $scope.nodata=true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    $scope.nodata=false; 
                 }
            });
```

getting link after updated the data in ng-src, But image alone is not visible, Is any mistake in my code

Comment: if something shows up after a refresh but not before, it is probably an issue with the rendering. Angularjs renders content on digest cycles, so if it doesn't, you should fix that either with a delay (`$timeout`) or a manual call (`$scope.$apply()`)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have used $apply - It throws an error like digest is already in progress, And If i use $timeout ,Initially it doesn't print any data after refresh only list of users displayed